# update multiple php files ( spacfice values , incressed by file squence)

Tags: php, linux, shell, sed

What is the right way  to do the following scenario

ive  100 Files db01.php  db100.php

which include this sql statement

```
$sql = mysql_query("select user from level2 where id BETWEEN 1 AND 350");

my gol is update value ( BETWEEN 1 AND 350 )
```

from db01.php to db100.php by adding +350

db02.php statement will be

```
   $sql = mysql_query("select user from level2 where id BETWEEN 350 AND 700");
```

db03.php

```
        $sql = mysql_query("select user from level2 where id BETWEEN 700 AND 1050");
```

.. go on till last file ,
what is the best way to  do this !

Comment: so you are updating 350 tables?

Comment: no updating the php files  values , then will execute  my php file

Comment: Why are there 100 php files? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: because of twitter API limit me by 350 call per hour and ive to update a huge number of users i need to use a 100 twitter app to update at minimum time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single PHP file with a get parameter witch indicate the "number" of your file (in your case, modify the start and end of your BETWEEN).

Try creating a PHP db.php file  :

```
$interval = 350;
$num = (int) $_GET["num"];

// Generate start and end (for between)
$start = (int) $interval * ($num - 1);
$end = (int) $interval * $num;

// Hack for the first number (start should be 1, not 0)
if($start == 0) $start = 1;

// Generate sql with $start and $end)
$sql = mysql_query("select user from level2 where id BETWEEN " . $start . " AND " . $end);
```

And then call it like this :

```
http://www.yourside.com/db.php?num=1
http://www.yourside.com/db.php?num=2
```

etc ...